# Filter Backbone collection on multiple model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, filter

I have a bit of a problem with how to best filter a Backbone collection on its models Attributes. My setup is like this:

I have a collection with several models in it. Each model has an attribute which holds an array of numbers ("type"). Like this:

```
- Collection
- model
    - id: 1
    - name
    - phone
    - type [3]
- model
    - id: 2
    - name
    - phone
    - type [2]
- model
    - id: 3
    - name
    - phone
    - type [1,2]
```

What I want to do here is to be able to filter this collections on the models "type" attribute.

I have this "type" attribute because this is for a contact list and each contact can be of several types. E.g. the collection should be able to be filtered on unlimited types. You should be able to filter on lets say type "1" and type "2" which will then show model 2 and model 3. Cause model 1 does not have the "type" 1.

Any good code examples or other help on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is code which can filter for multiple types, stored in array

```
var typesTofilter=[5,1,2];//array of type tobe search.
    var f2=friends.filter(function(o){ var accept=false;                                    
                                       $(typesTofilter).each(function(i,val){
                                         if(_.indexOf(o.get('type'), val) >-1){
                                           accept= true;                      
                                            }
                                        })
                                        return accept; 
                         });
```

And here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninad/2Cm4h/1/).

Comment: Thanks man! Worsk great. If i now want to reset my currently rendered collection with the matching result?

Comment: Nevermind. manage to figure it out. It was really simple, just used the collection.reset() and passed the new result in. Also had the collection to listen for a change event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
var filColl=myColl.filter(function(o){return _.indexOf(o.get('type'), 1) >-1 })
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninad/2Cm4h/) link of working code,with some sample data.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, this works great for type 1. But i was wondering how i could do it a bit more dynamic? The type can sometimes be both 1 and 2 for example. This filtering runs on a click event. So i was thinking of just push the type as a data-attr into an array on the click. And then filter it depending on what types that array currently holding. (matching it to the collection)